# How it it possible for Wayland compositors to use keyboard/mouse without root access?

Tags: linux, wayland

I installed the Weston compositor on a Ubuntu laptop just to test it. When launching it from a text console, it opens and works fine, using DRM to draw the interface and evdev to read input devices like the keyboard and mouse. How is Weston able to read the keyboard without being launched as root? I thought the Linux evdev interface could not be read by a non-root user for security reasons. Even the files listed in the Weston Ubuntu package show, to me, nothing that would configure the system to allow reading evdev without admin privileges (like udev rules, for example). How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Weston uses *seats* to access input devices. It’s basically a way to gain privileged access to certain devices by being physically located at the machine.

> You can start Weston from a VT assuming that there’s a seat manager supported by libseat running, such as seatd or logind.

[Source](https://wayland.pages.freedesktop.org/weston/toc/running-weston.html)

From the [seatd description](https://sr.ht/%7Ekennylevinsen/seatd/):

> What is seat management?
>
> Seat management takes care of mediating access to shared devices (graphics, input), without requiring the applications needing access to be root.

On your standard run-of-the-mill Linux system, you’ll probably have *systemd* and as such *logind*.

The [libseat API](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekennylevinsen/seatd/tree/master/item/include/libseat.h) is very simple and well-documented, if you’re interested.

For communication with *logind*, *libseat* uses the [*org.freedesktop.login1*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.login1.html) DBus interface. The basic explanation is that this works by passing around file descriptors.